# How to center text inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the text horizontally in the middle of the orange div container. Here is the styling and the actual code.

```
.header{
            background: #ff6400;
            height:40px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .phone{
            color: white; 
            font-size: 20px; 
            padding: 9px 0 0 125px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .adres{
            display: inline-block;
            color: white; 
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="phone">&#9742; 052 824 134</div>
    <div class="adres">&#10031; бул. Княз Борис I, No 115 - Дворец на Културата и Спорта</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to center text in a div questions shouldn't get new answer anymore guys. This question has already been answered billions of times. @Kristiyan Rusev : try searching this forum before posting a question. It is very likely that such a basic CSS issue is answered already around here. Welcome to this forum by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

align: center;

```
.adres{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: white; 
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this aligned the text just the way I wanted it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to `.header` and remove the left padding from `.phone`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex box

like this :

```css
.header{
            background: #ff6400;
            height:80px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
            flex-direction:column;
        }
        .phone{
            color: white; 
            font-size: 20px; 
            padding: 9px 0 0 125px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .adres{
            display: inline-block;
            color: white; 
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="phone">&#9742; 052 824 134</div>
    <div class="adres">&#10031; бул. Княз Борис I, No 115 - Дворец на Културата и Спорта</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header{
  background: #ff6400;
  height:40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.